# Can we access Bot project settings in Bot Composer?

Tags: botframework

I've been pouring through Bot Composer documentation and samples, but have not found what I'm looking for. Basically, I've added a custom bot configuration setting (from 'Configure' in the nav bar) by turning on the "Advanced Settings View (json)" and adding it directly in the JSON document.
So far so good, the composer doesn't complain... but I have no idea how to access this property from within a Bot composer object. Is there any syntax that would allow me to access this property inside, say a response template or property value? I guess the larger question is - how do you set and use application settings in Bot Composer? What is the equivalent of appettings.json?

Comment: Do you want access the Configure property ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `settings` memory scope. Would be something like `settings.mycustombotsettingsobject.customsetting1`. Please see information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/ref-memory-variables?tabs=v2x) on how to accomplish that.